# How to Edit env.php file for Magento2?

Tags: magento2, database, server-setup

I need help to fix my Magento 2.x website without losing any data. Recently my running Magento 2.x website is down and showing "New Installation" process.

I have found the problem with the "env.php" file has no data saved. I don't know how it's missing from the env.php file.

I was trying to add the PHP configuration back code into the env.php file using by via SSH key but unfortunately, the file can't save with my inputted data.

It's showing Error doing I have open env.php file using NANO env.php and add all the date and press Ctrl+O to save the data but it's gonna save.

Showing warning like No Free space.

Answer (score 1):

There is no space left on your server so you have several options:

- Upgrade the Server
- Empty the var/log , var/report
- Remove old session files (only if you saved session in file storage) | https://support.hypernode.com/knowledgebase/how-to-free-up-disk-space/#Do_you_have_too_many_files_Do_you_run_out_of_inodes
- Check log tables and maybe clean up